# Open a file from firefox bookmark

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I am very often using bookmarks in Firefox

I want to open a file/program, for example **Microsoft outlook** from Firefox bookmark

So if I click the bookmark, the file/program will opened in PC

Please help I really need this, there should be someway to do that

Comment: Are you using Windows? Why not just pin it to the taskbar instead of trying to do it through a browser? Browsers are made for accessing the internet, not programs on your computer.

Comment: You used to be able to just bookmark `file:///c:/users/me/myDocument.docx`. Doesn't seem to work any more.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the file saved as a bookmark, you could [change the way Firefox handles downloading the MIME type](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file).

Go to: **Preferences > Applications** and select the type of file you want to change the action for.

You will receive a drop-down menu that will give you a selectable list of actions to take whenever you click on the specific type of file.  You can also specify a specific program of your choosing to open your file type with.